Chow-Künneth conjecture and Galois base change
Consider $K'|K$ a finite galois extension of degre $m$ and galois group $G$. Recall the Chow-Künneth conjecture :
Conjecture
For any (smooth projective) variety over a field $k$ and  $H$ a Weil cohomology, there are cycles $\pi_i\in CH(X\times X)$ such that

$H(\pi_i)=\Delta_i$ the Künneth projector.
$\pi_i$ are idempotents and orthogonals for the composition of cycles.

Now consider we know the conjecture over $K'$, would this imply the conjecture over $K$ ? It seems obvious in some articles, but I never find a serious proof of this, or with no mistake. I have two ideas of proof but a detail is missing.
First attempt
Lemma
If $X$ is a variety over $K$ and $X'$ is its base extension over $K'$, we consider $q : X' \rightarrow X$ the canonical morphism. Then we have $CH(X')^G\simeq CH
(X)$ via $q^\star$ and $\frac{1}{m}q_\star$.
With this lemma we can deduce easily the following fact :
Proposition
If we solve the Chow-Künneth over $K'$ with $G$-invariants cycles, then we have Chow-Künneth over $K$.
However I don't know how to generate $G$-invariants projectors. My idea was to consider
$\pi_i'=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{\sigma \in G} \sigma\cdot \pi$
It clearly satisfies the first condition in the Chow-Künneth conjecture, but I don't see why it would be idempotent orthogonal (the problem is that in general for a group acting on a ring, the projector on the invariant part is not a ring morphism).
Question
Do you see any reason in this specific case to have a ring morphism ? In the calculation I don't know what to say about $\sigma\cdot \pi_i \circ \pi_i$.
Second attempt (edit : thanks to a comment this one hase a counterexample)
If $\pi_i$ are projectors for the Chow-Künneth conjecture over $K'$, consider $\frac{1}{m}q_\star(\pi_i)$, then it satisfies the first part of the conjecture, but for the second one I would need that $\frac{1}{m}q_\star$ respects the ring strucutre. It is clearly the case on the invariant subring, but I am not sure about the general case.
Claim
Basic calculations show that it reduces to the formula
$q_\star(\alpha\cap \beta)=\frac{1}{m}(q_\star(\alpha))\cap(q_\star(\beta))$
for two cycles $\alpha,\beta$. If we know that either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is $G$-invariant, we can write it as a pull-back and conclude by the projection formula.
Question
Is this formula still true in the general case ?
Third attempt
I have a proof for my question if we assume that the homological ideal over $K'$ is nilpotent (it would follow from others conjectures like Bloch-Beilinson, but it is not known actually). However I would like to avoid using another conjecture.
If you have any idea about just one of my question, it would be a pleasure.

The formula in your second attempt does not hold in general. For a simple example, assume $K'/K$ is quadratic and $X$ is the descent of $X' = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ (over $K'$) using the involution given by permutation of the factors. Then take $\alpha = \beta = p \times \mathbb{P}^1$, where $p \in \mathbb{P}^1(K')$ is any point.

Also, note that the candidate cycle in the first attempt is equal to the pullback of the candidate cycle in the second attempt, so both attempts are really the same.

@naf yes it was on purpose, I thought it may be easier to use one instead of the other. But in any case there is something wrong in the end. I guess I will have to satisfy myself of the statement I checked in my third attempt : Bloch-Beilinson conjecture on K' imply Chow-Kunneth on K (and probably also Bloch-Beilinson on K).

OK. Without knowing uniqueness of the Chow-Kunneth components it is not clear how they can be descended, so some extra input is definitely needed.
